# Formula always return one value for each cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I was querying a hyperlink row from one sheet to another using this formula:

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:$F, "SELECT E WHERE C = 'fragment' ")
```

However I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57838104/415078) that it copying only text but not the whole thing. After some research I found out that I can solve that problem by using this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(Data!A2:$F, "SELECT E WHERE C = 'fragment' "),Data!E:E,1,FALSE))
```

However the problem now I have is that formula put same value on each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` to keep hyperlinks, like this:

`=filter(Data!E2:E, Data!C2:C = "fragment")`