# Reference cell url when using filter or query fucntions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using functions like FILTER or QUERY to bring data from one sheet to another.

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:$D, "SELECT B WHERE C = 'fragment' ")

=FILTER(Data!E2:E, Data!C2:C = "fragment")
```

Is it possible to bring the link reference to the printed cell or row to be able to navigate to that?

It is seems that I had to turn the column text values into hyperlinks like that https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/edit#gid=123&range=XYZ.

Do you have any ideas? May be I had to use app script for that?

Comment: Please show a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Comment: That formula is from [Formula always return one value for each cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167089/269219). When you copy or closely rephrase content that you did not create into something you post, always insert proper [attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=filter( 
  { 
    Data!E2:E, 
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/edit#gid=123&range=E" 
    & 
    row(Data!E2:E) 
  }, 
  Data!C2:C = "fragment" 
)
```

Comment: can you do same using query at all?

Comment: `query()` only shows values and does not include rich text formatting such as links. See the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167089/269219) to your previous question.

Comment: oh, would you mind to suggest how to reference a more then one cell, like the whole row? I believe the difference would be by passing the right range `....&range=X:Y` but haven't figure-out that just yet. Here is a new question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/167119/reference-row-url-when-using-filter-fucntion