# Reference row url when using filter fucntion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have this function that reference a specific cell

```
  =filter( 
  { 
    Data!E2:E, 
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/edit#gid=123&range=E" 
    & 
    row(Data!E2:E) 
  }, 
  Data!C2:C = "fragment"
)
```

or

```
=filter( 
  { 
    Data!E2:E, 
    HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/edit#gid=123&range=E"edit#gid=123&range=A" 
    & 
    row(Data!E2A2:E$A), Data!A2:$A) 
  }, 
  DataRoutes!C2:C$C = "fragment" 
)
```

I wonder how would you change that to reference the whole row or multiple cells?

Comment: That formula is from [Reference cell url when using filter or query fucntions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167098/269219). When you copy or closely rephrase content that you did not create into something you post, always insert proper [attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Your new version of the formula will error out the minute you insert or delete a row on either of the `Data` and `Routes` sheets. Please describe the _problem_ you are trying to solve rather than asking for improvements to a _possible solution_ you think would work. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: @doubleunary ok, I did rollback the question and accept your answer. here is the edited one https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/167126/reference-row-url-when-using-hyperlink-and-filter-fucntion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to a whole row, use a reference like `42:42`. Here's a formula to get those references as URLs:

```
=filter( 
  { 
    Data!E2:E, 
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/edit#gid=123&range=" 
    & 
    row(Data!E2:E) & ":" & row(Data!E2:E) 
  }, 
  Data!C2:C = "fragment"
)
```

To get nicer links, use `hyperlink()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  hyperlink( 
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/edit#gid=123&range=" 
    & 
    row(Data!A2:A) & ":" & row(Data!A2:A), 
    Data!A2:A 
  ), 
  Data!C2:C = "fragment"
)
```

Comment: sorry originally I placed a wrong formula, just updated